# Is there a default default constructor?

Tags: c++

If you don't provide a copy constructor, one is created automatically. This is called the default copy constructor.
A default constructor is a constructor that doesn't take any parameters.
If you don't provide any constructors, a default constructor is created automatically.
Is this called the default default constructor?

Comment: it's called default ctor.

Comment: "A default constructor is X. Is X called default default constructor?"

Comment: That's not what I asked.

Comment: Do you have a reference to an implicitly declared copy constructor being called a "default copy constructor?"

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor

Comment: +1 just because this doesn't deserve so many downvotes

Comment: @NeilKirk Someone should put a `[citation needed]` on that Wiki page. There's just one occurence of the phrase "default copy" in the C++11 standard, and it's in a comment in an example. That's non-normative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the [default constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_constructor) is called a “default constructor” in both cases, whether it is provided explicitly or is automatically generated by the compiler.

Answer (score 4):

Well, to be fair the C++ Standard does speak, in paragraph 12.1-5, of *defaulted default constructors*.

Comment: Note the difference between "default" and "defaultED"

Answer (score 2):

No. It's always called the default constructor.

Answer (score 2):

It can be called an "implicitly defined default constructor", if you insist. C++11 §12.1/6

> A default constructor that is defaulted and not defined as deleted is ***implicitly defined*** ...

Comment: +1 For most precise answer. And I don't understand downvotes. Some way to punish good answers to bad questions?

Comment: The quote does not strictly state its name is "implicitly defined default constructor" nor does it mean it can't be called "default default constructor"